# which columns can be paired together with the fewest NAs?

Tags: r

I have measured several attributes of a few chemicals, but I don't have a value for every attribute of each chemical.

I would like to know which tests I can use as the X and Y dimensions of a scatter plot, such that I will have the highest number of data points.

If my tests looked like this:

```
> mydata
      testA testB testC testD
chem1   0.6   0.2    NA   0.8
chem2   0.1    NA   0.9    NA
chem3   0.3   0.4   0.5    NA
```

I would like to see a table like this, that indicates testA vs. testB, or testA vs. testC would have the "most" data points.

```
> mycounts
      testA testB testC testD
testA    NA    NA    NA    NA
testB     2    NA    NA    NA
testC     2     1    NA    NA
testD     1     1     0    NA
```

I have a little experience with reshape, data.table and plyr, but I can't figure how to do something like this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want something like

```
x <- !is.na(as.matrix(mydata))
z <- crossprod(x,x)
z
```

which gives

```
      testA testB testC testD
testA     3     2     2     1
testB     2     2     1     1
testC     2     1     2     0
testD     1     1     0     1
```

And if you really need to turn the upper diag to NA, you can do

```
z[upper.tri(z, diag=T)]<-NA
z
```

to get

```
      testA testB testC testD
testA    NA    NA    NA    NA
testB     2    NA    NA    NA
testC     2     1    NA    NA
testD     1     1     0    NA
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for.  I guess I need to brush up on matrix operations.  You know, I think you helped me with other R questions I posted in the past anonymously (without a permanent account.)  So many, many thanks.